# Vectors tangent to a ring in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create an image with Tikz similar to this

[image: t]

and I wrote this code, partially based on the code [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72959/3d-plane-and-rotating-coordinate-system-in-tikz) as

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\xangle}{7}
\newcommand{\yangle}{137.5}
\newcommand{\zangle}{90}

\newcommand{\xlength}{1}
\newcommand{\ylength}{0.5}
\newcommand{\zlength}{1}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{\xlength*cos(\xangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xy}{\xlength*sin(\xangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yx}{\ylength*cos(\yangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\ylength*sin(\yangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zx}{\zlength*cos(\zangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zy}{\zlength*sin(\zangle)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   x={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},
    y={(\yx cm,\yy cm)},
    z={(\zx cm,\zy cm)},
]

\draw[dashed] (0,0,0) circle (4.5);


\draw[blue!80!black,->] (240:4.5) -- (240:5.5);
\node[blue!80!black] at (240:5.8) {y};
\draw[green!80!black,->] (240:4.5) -- ++(0,0,1);
\node[green!80!black] at ($(240:4.5)+(0,0,1.2)$) {z};
\draw[red!80!black,->] (240:4.5) -- ++ (240+90:1);
\node[red!80!black] at ($(240:4.5)+(240+90:1.3)$) {x};
\fill[black!50!gray,draw=black!50!black] (240:4.5) circle (0.05cm);

\foreach \d in {0,60,120,180,240,300}
{
    \draw[thick, black,->] (\d:4.5) -- ++(1,1,1);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I obtain all the vector pointing in the same direction. How can I fix it to be similar to the first figure? And also how can I add the angles \alpha and \beta as in the first figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tikz-3dplot` here. It allows you to switch to rotated coordinates. My take is that you really want to parallel-transport a *rotated* vector, as in your screen shot. Parallel-transport of the tangent would be much easier, you only need to use the xy plane. (Please let me know if this is what you want.)

The rotation angles of the vector that is to be parallel transported are stored in the "functions" `alpha` and `beta`. They can be adjusted at will, as well as the view angles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{00}%<- set view angles
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,line cap=round,
    tdplot_main_coords,%<- install 3d view
    declare function={R=4;alpha=-40;beta=-50;}%<- radius of the circle and angles
    ]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \draw[semithick] (0,0) circle[radius=R];
  \draw[thick,->,blue] (-1.5,-R) -- ++ (3,0) node[right]{$t$};
  \draw (1,-R) arc[start angle=0,end angle=alpha,radius=1];
  \path foreach \X in {0,...,5}
  {(-90+\X*60:R) coordinate (p\X)}; % points along the circle
 \end{scope}
 % rotated plane at p0
 \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{alpha}{0}{0}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,canvas is xz plane at y=0,shift={(p0)}]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle ++ ((90+beta:{1/abs(cos(alpha))}) (1,0) node[right]{$\alpha$};
  \draw[thick,->,red]  (-90+beta:{1/abs(cos(alpha))})
     -- ++ (90+beta:{2/abs(cos(alpha))});
  \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,1) node[above]{$z$};    
  \draw (0,0.5) arc[start angle=90,end angle=90+beta,radius=0.5]
      node[midway,above right] {$\beta$};
 \end{scope}
 % other planes
 \foreach \X in {1,...,5}
 {\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{alpha}{0}{\X*60}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,canvas is xz plane at y=0,shift={(p\X)}]
  \draw[thick,->,red]  (-90+beta:{1/abs(cos(alpha))})
     -- ++ (90+beta:{2/abs(cos(alpha))});
 \end{scope}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]