# Rotate whole coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows, axis

I'm kinda new in TikZ, so question may sound stupid. How can I rotate the whole coordinate system? This is what I have (simple 3D coordinate system):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, z=-0.6cm]
    % Axes
    \begin{scope}[rotate=0]
    \draw [<->] (-3,0,0) -- (12,0,0) node [at end, right] {$z$};
    \draw [<->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) node [at end, left] {$y$};
    \draw [<->] (0,0,2) -- (0,0,-4) node [at end, left] {$x$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So, this is an output:

[image]

And, this is what I'm trying to represent (I'm talking only about coordinate system and how it rotated):

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72959/3d-plane-and-rotating-coordinate-system-in-tikz) should be of great interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this solution from Tom Bombadil](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72959/3d-plane-and-rotating-coordinate-system-in-tikz), you can adjust each axis to give it the angle and aspect you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\xangle}{30}
    \newcommand{\yangle}{90}
    \newcommand{\zangle}{-10}
    
    \newcommand{\xlength}{1}
    \newcommand{\ylength}{0.5}
    \newcommand{\zlength}{1}
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{\xlength*cos(\xangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xy}{\xlength*sin(\xangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yx}{\ylength*cos(\yangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\ylength*sin(\yangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zx}{\zlength*cos(\zangle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zy}{\zlength*sin(\zangle)}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        x={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},
        y={(\yx cm,\yy cm)},
        z={(\zx cm,\zy cm)}
        ]
        % Axes
        \begin{scope}
        \draw [<->] (-2,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node [at end, right] {$x$};
        \draw [<->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) node [at end, left] {$y$};
        \draw [<->] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,6) node [at end, above] {$z$};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

edit: I deleted two lines in the code that were redundant (copy fail).